# Изучаю Code First и получаю ошибку Cannot open database. Помогите разобраться

Tags: c#, entity-framework

В рамках изучения подхода Code-First состряпал небольшой учебный проект. После первой компиляции этого кода в папке %USERPROFILE% создается файл базы данных и все работает отлично. Но если базу данных удалить, то повторно она не создается. Выдается ошибка при компиляции:

> An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the
>   InnerException for details.
>
> The underlying provider failed on Open
>
> Cannot open database "WindowsFormsApplication1.BudgetContext"
>   requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user
>   'COMPUTER_NAME\user'.

Помогите разобраться, почему база данных не создается повторно?

**Полный код программы**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            using (var db = new BudgetContext())
            {
                var goodsList = new GoodsList { Name = "Test Goods List" };
                db.GoodsList.Add(goodsList);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
    }

    public class BudgetContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Goods> Goods { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GoodsList> GoodsList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Goods
    {
        public int GoodsID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public int barcode { get; set; }

        public int GoodsListID { get; set; }
        public virtual GoodsList GoodsList { get; set; }
    }

    public class GoodsList
    {
        public int GoodsListID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Goods> Goods { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**UPD:**

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1934e089b77a5c56" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**UPD2:**

> Информация о среде:
>
> OS Windows 10 ([Version 10.0.10240]),
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.00079
>
> Entity Framework 6.1.3

Comment: По идее, такого быть не должно, если не используете миграции. А если используете, то их надо тоже удалить и затем опять создать первую миграцию руками.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko при использовании миграций их не обязательно удалять для пересоздания бд, `update-database` создаст бд в случае её отсутствия

Comment: перечитал ошибку, указанную Вами, пропишите `ConnectionString` явно с указанием пути, и имени создаваемой бд. в приведенном Вами `App.config` я не вижу строки соединения

Comment: @Bald56rus А как же БД тогда создалась при первой компиляции программы и почему она успешно создается при применении метода **DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges**?

Comment: что бы избавиться от всяких предположения я предпочитаю прописывать явно, у Меня прекрасно работает `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`. и так же у меня создается секция в config следующего вида `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\db.sdf;" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>` почему её нет у Вас странно

Comment: @Bald56rus Я изначально хотел разобраться в причинах, а не просто получить готовый вариант. Буду Вам примного благодарен, если Вы поможете.

Comment: что бы попытаться разобраться в причинах, надо знать Вашу среду, т.е. версию студии, используемых библиотек, что бы можно было попробовать смоделировать, потому что у меня `Visual Studio 2013 Community` `Entity Framework 6.1.3` и все работает, если Вы добавите в вопрос указанную мной информацию попробую смоделировать и что то подсказать

Comment: @Bald56rus Обновил пост, внес информацию.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32438/discussion-between-bald56rus-and-mikhail-danshin).

Comment: @Bald У меня такая же ошибка. Можете мне помочь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class BudgetContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Goods> Goods { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GoodsList> GoodsList { get; set; }

    public BudgetContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<BudgetContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<BudgetContext>());
    }
}
```

БД будет создана при её отсутствии.

Более подробно можно почитать [здесь](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

**UPD:**
попробуйте добавить строку подключения в config явно, вот так она выглядит у меня:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=CSCP.Web-2-1-alpha1;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Почитал, вроде все просто, но почему-то не помогает. В трассировке видно, что строка ***Database.SetInitializer<BudgetContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<BudgetContext>());*** выполняется, но база данных не создается. :(

Comment: @MikhailDanshin покажите `ConnectionString`, может Вы базу не там ищете?!

Comment: Дело в том, что никакой **ConnectionString** я не писал руками с самого начала. После установки **EntityFramework** в app.config прописались строки автоматом. Обновил свой пост, включил в него app.config. Базу ищу в папке **%USERPROFILE%**, где она создалась изначально. Откуда я ее и удалил.

Comment: А вот **DropCreateDatabaseAlways** помогло! Почему?

Comment: @Mikhail Danshin У меня такая же проблема. Поначалу БД создавалась, а через несколько попыток перестала создаваться. Вы нашли причину?

Comment: @SVD102 если в своем проекте вы используете механизм миграций, то можно попробовать команду `update-database`, которая создаст бд в случае её отсутствия или приведет к актуальному сосоянию

Comment: @Bald В обозревателе серверов удалил базу данных, которую не мог создать. Физически файла БД уже не существовало, на момент удаления. И при удалении я получал ошибку.После всех этих действий я успешно создал заново БД.

Comment: @SVD102 а для чего Вы постоянно пересоздаете бд?

Comment: @Bald Я не пересоздаю БД, если нет БД, то я ее создаю, если БД уже есть то я обращаюсь к ней. Но я не мог обратиться к существующей БД. И создать другую БД.